# Win32 Window resize animation

Tags: windows, animation, mfc, win32gui

I want to resize a Window with animation in my 32 application. I have searched everywhere but I couldn't find Win32/MFC APIs to do so. The animation behavior I need is very simple. It's just scaling up the height of the Window. Kindly let me know how can I achieve this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve some custom animation effects using GDI.  Start by getting the coordinates and position of the window using GetWindowRect.  Hide the window using ShowWindow.  Now draw your animation using DrawRect, FillRect, etc in a timer.  I would recommend filling the rectangle using the system window color.  Then show/resize the window again using ShowWindow when the animation is complete.

Answer (score -1):

Look at ::AnimateWindow(). MSDN link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632669%28v=vs.85%29.aspx .

Comment: Hi Roel, AnimateWindow looks very promising for animation. But how can I resize from height 598 to let's say 674?

Comment: You're right and I was mistaken; AnimateWindow() is only for showing/hiding windows. You'll have to roll your own animation. You can either do it manually (resize the window step by step with a timer every 100 ms or so); apparently there is also a class for interpolation in various ways in the SP1 update to VS2010 (http://www.nuonsoft.com/blog/2010/12/16/the-new-mfc-animation-api/) but I have never worked with it.